# at stroke of midnight, at the stroke of midnight and on the stroke of midnight

Tags: phrase-usage

> BREAKING: This is the video of vandal defacing @KingJames mural **at stroke of midnight** this am in #Venice. Video from @BabyBluesBBQ surveillance cam.  @Lakers @NBCLA.

I doubt the usage of *at stroke of midnight*, which I think it should be *at the stroke of midnight* instead.

I also see *on the stroke of midnight* in dictionaries. So, I am wondering what's the difference between *at the stroke of midnight* and *on the stroke of midnight*? In my opinion, *at the stroke of midnight* seems to make more sense because **at** denotes a point of time. Any thoughts?

The [full source](https://sports.yahoo.com/lebron-james-sporting-lakers-shorts-receives-standing-ovation-upon-arrival-summer-league-204624830.html?guccounter=1).

Comment: It's *At the stroke of midnight*.  But Twitter only allows so many characters, so people remove unnecessary words.

Comment: Outside of Twitter, the place you're most likely to encounter *At stroke of midnight* is in a poem, or perhaps in an incantation. In normal conversation the article is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"At (or on) *the* stroke of midnight". The quoted text is either a mistake, or because they are trying to save characters.

Both at or on are used. "On" perhaps emphasises the "momentary" nature. We say "On Monday" to mean when an event happens that is less than a day long, so "On the stroke" means that the event is even shorter than the "stroke of midnight". But both at and on are used.